# Positive integral solutions $(m,n)$ to $m = n^m$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Are there any positive integral solutions $(m,n)$ to the diophatine equation $n=m^{n}$ besides $(m,n)=(1,1)$? Not sure how to approach this question. I got the (obvious) solution by guessing. It seems clear that $m\leq{n}$.

Comment: Hint: If $m \neq 1$ then $n \geq 2^{n}$.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy The given equation gives this (wrong) inequality so  we get  a contradiction.

Comment: It does not really matter, but you used another equation in the title than in the body.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Combine what I wrote with the strict inequality $2^{n} >n$ (which follows from Binomial Theorem, for example).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why this indirect proof ? We just need $2^n>n$ for every positive integer $n$ (can easily be proven by induction). Then, if $m>1$ , we have $m^n\ge 2^n>n$ , hence $n=m^n$ cannot hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I won't argue further, but I don't see a logic in what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

$$m=1^m$$ has the only (and obvious) solution $m=1$.

There are no other solutions to the initial problem, as

$$m<2^m<3^m<\cdots$$

[By induction, $1<2^1$ and $m<2^m\implies m+1<2m<2^{m+1}$.]

Comment: Modulo exchange of $m$ and $n$ if needed.

Answer (score 1):

No,there are no other positive integral solutions except the one you have already guessed. For this solution ,I would be replacing (n,m) with (x,y).(as I comfortable in solving with those variables)

$\implies$$x=y^{x}$

$\implies y=x^{1/x}$

By differentiating the expression,you will realise that the maximum value of the expression is at $e$ which is $e^{1/e}$. You can prove that $e^{1/e}<2$ since $\frac{1}{e} (≈0.37)< ln(2) {≈0.69}$.

[image]

As,you can observe that the only integral value that y can be is 1.Thus the only positive integral solutions is (1,1).